# Can't run ./gradlew --tasks on Linux Mint: Could not determine java version from '11.0.6

Tags: android, gradle

gradle version 6.0

gradle wrapper settings:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

On Windows 10 I success run command

```
gradlew --tasks
```

but  on Linux Mint 19 I try this and get error:

```
  ./gradlew --tasks

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '11.0.6'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: Gradle 4.4 doesn't support Java 11

Comment: You need at least Gradle 5.0 https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/release-notes.html#java-11-runtime-support

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading your gradle version. The latest one at the moment is:

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
```

Alternatively, try downgrading your java version after comparing the java versions on your Windows and Ubuntu. Good luck.